# How to add a directory to a JAR file with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I'm trying to package a web application as a runnable JAR file with Maven. The *jar-with-dependencies* assembly takes care of including all the dependencies, but I still need to include *src/main/webapp*.

I managed to add the directory to my JAR with a custom assembly:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2
                              http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>webapp</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/webapp</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets> 
</assembly>
```

And it does work, and it's even possible to use this assembly together with *jar-with-dependencies*. However, the final JAR contains the webapp directory and all dependencies, but not the class files of my project. My assembly is apparently removing them.

Can I preserve the class files of my own project in an assembly? Or is there another way to add a directory to a JAR?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My assembly is apparently removing them

I'm guessing it's the other way around, it's *not adding* them.

Your class files are inside target/classes and they need to go inside target/webapp/WEB-INF/classes. I'm guessing you need another rule like this:

```
<fileSet>
    <directory>target/classes</directory>
    <outputDirectory>/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
</fileSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You classes will be generated in **${project.build.directory}/classes** (/target/classes probably).

Therefore, you should use that folder as source directory.

Try to change `<directory>src/main/webapp</directory>` into `<directory>{project.build.directory}/classes</directory>`

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you could add the following in your assembly descriptor. This would take care of not only putting the class files, but also the webapp contents, assuming your maven project is building a webapp.

```
...
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
...
```